# How to convert 8-bit unsigned int to integer or string in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I query data form database and I get 8-bit unsigned int, but I can't use it because ruby will change that to boolean.

Can I convert 8-bit unsigned int to integer or string?

Thank you

Comment: Can you post result of `puts yourint.inspect; puts yourint.class`?

Comment: We need to see some code showing how you are accessing the database. I recommend using the Sequel ORM, but there are plenty of other ways to access a database, and I haven't seen any return a value that I couldn't use immediately if it was something supported by the driver.

Answer (score 0):

This happens with ActiveRecord and MySQL, which considers a `tinyint(1)` (an 8-bit integer) to  be a a boolean value, because MySQL didn't have any boolean type prior to 5.0 (it has BIT now).  You can disable this behavior completely, but I don't know of a way to disable it per-field or per-model, so you lose the "boolean" behavior on other fields if you disable it.  Fortunately, that's probably not a big deal, because 0 will still be false in most contexts, and anything else will still be true.

You can disable it by putting this into `config/application.rb`:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter.emulate_booleans = false
```

See [the ActiveRecord API docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/s/square-activerecord-3.0.7/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/MysqlAdapter.html).